# Django 2.2 - Testcase - client.logout() method does not log out user

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing

I am writing tests for my simple Django web application, checking if user can login and logout correctly. Views:`user_login` and `user_logout`

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.POST.get('email address')
        password = request.POST.get('password')
        user = authenticate(username=email, password=password)
        if user:
            if user.is_active:
                login(request, user)
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main_page:index'))
        else:
            print("\nWARNING: invalid login detected\n\nemail: {}\npassword: {}\n".format(email, password))
            messages.error(request, 'Ivalid email or password. Try again.')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('users:login'))
    else:
        return render(request, 'users/login.html', {})


@login_required
def user_logout(request):
    messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'See you Space Cowboy!')
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('main_page:index'))
```

And the tests themself:

```
class LoginLogoutTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        User = get_user_model()
        self.user = User.objects.create_user(email='test_user@email.com', password='S6y4Mb9Aqfu79YcF')
        print("\nsetup")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.user
        print("teardown\n")

    def test_login(self):
        # test if email is equal
        self.assertEqual(self.user.email, 'test_user@email.com')
        # test authentication
        self.assertTrue(self.user.is_authenticated)
        self.assertFalse(self.user.is_anonymous)
        # test if login request index.html
        self.assertTrue(self.client.get('main_page.index.html'))
        # test login with valid credentials
        self.assertTrue(self.client.login(email='test_user@email.com', password='S6y4Mb9Aqfu79YcF'))
        # test login with invalid credentials
        self.assertFalse(self.client.login(email='test_user@email.com', password='password'))
        print("test login")

    def test_logout(self):
        self.client.logout()
        self.assertTrue(self.user.is_authenticated)
        self.assertFalse(self.user.is_anonymous)
        print("test logout\n")
```

Tests return this output:

```
(venv) [user@manjaro django-project]$ ./manage.py test
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).

setup
test login
teardown

setup
test logout
teardown

..
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 2 tests in 0.515s

OK
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Last test shouldn't be passed, but paradoxically it is. What goes here wrong?

EDIT:
I rebuilt user model that it uses email as login. I used this tutorial: https://testdriven.io/blog/django-custom-user-model/

Comment: Looks like you passed the tests?  What is your concern?

Comment: It shouldn't be passing last test, because I logged out user and then checked if he is anonymous . But paradoxically, he is still authenticated

Comment: In the test_logout function, what is `self.client.logout()`?  That does not appear to be the same function that is called in the real user_logout view.

Comment: @john-gordon: that's a proper way to logout logged user during tests in Django. Django's TestCase is expanded unittests' TestCase and client is one of those specifics in it. Not used properly in this case tho.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't tested your app, those views you provided have nothing in common with provided tests. You have tried to test Django itself, its TestCase internals and kind of failed to test it right: after that logout do the similar like in your login test, assert that your index page isn't reachable by your client.

The proper way to test your views would be by pointing client to their corresponding urls, both AnonymousUser and a logged one.